# Laravel Nova: Datetime with format and pickerFormat combined does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-6

I got the fallowing date time field:

```php
DateTime
    ::make('foobar')
    ->format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss') // https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/
    ->pickerFormat('d-m-Y H:i:S') // https://flatpickr.js.org/formatting/
    ->rules('required', 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ->firstDayOfWeek(1)
```

Momentjs does not recognise the date. I get a warning after changing the date in console:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
```

It seems like momentjs is not getting the format? But I am clearly setting it in the nova resource and so it should get passed to vue, and so on? right?

Removing `->pickerFormat()` allows me to save the date, but without displaying it the way I want in the picker.

I might be doing it completely wrong, so if someone could produce a working example of a DateTime filed with format and pickerFormat then that would be great as well.

edit:

Some more info. I re-transpiled Nova's using dev mode so I could poke around using Vue (chrome extension) tool.

I have also looked at the DateTime (vue) component without success. To bad it is closed source.

Comment: What was the date string that generated this deprecation?  I mean, on the javascript side, not what Laravel thinks it is.  You should be able to pick it out of the response somewhere and console.log it.

Comment: There is no request/response needed to get the error. If I create a new resource with a DateTime I do notice strange things like for instance when I click on the datetime field I dont see the time (as if it was a date field instead). When I click away and click on it again it does show the time. This is so annoying. Btw, if you are able to create a working combination of format and pickerFormat I would like to see the values you used. The above should be easy to recreate if you just combine those fields.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Nova.  I've just been wrestling with Laravel and PHP's drecksome date handling for some months now.  One thing you might want to check for is if there are any null or zero dates in your database.  PHP will (wrongly) render these as negative dates once timezone adjustment is done, and those are nonsensical to moment's parser.

Comment: Nope, this had nothing to do with php... it had all todo with JavaScript's Date() function that does not understand a date formatted like "day-month-year". I have already found the fix and going to continue the issue here: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2037

Answer (score 0):

Use the package lathanhvien/novaofdatetime I just wrote recently. Hope it’s good to you!

Package link: https://packagist.org/packages/lathanhvien/novaofdatetime

Comment: I am sorry, but I like my "fix" better because I use a feature thats already in flatpickr: https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#human-friendly-dates Before writing custom code, you should first check what the script/code you are extending offers. However, creating a new package that adds a "better" (form)field is indeed a better solution than forking Nova.